# Ruby on Rails:How to translate options of select tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a select element in one edit user form with:

```
t.select :identification_type, User.identification_type_hash
```

The hash is

```
{ :type_1 => 1, :type_2 => 2, ... }
```

I need to localize type name. But I didn't find the correct way to add translation into that yml file in locale directory.

I have tryed

```
en_US:
  type_1: Translationg of type 1
  type_2: Translationg of type 1

  active_record:
    attributes:
      identification_type:
        type_1: Translationg of type 1
        type_2: Translationg of type 1

  identification_type:
    type_1: Translationg of type 1
    type_2: Translationg of type 1
```

No one above works. (while translation of other things still works.)
And I failed to find a solution in ROR document.

So what is the correct way to localize these hash value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to translate the keys yourself, but this is easy. Assume you have the following locale file:

```
en_US:
  identification_type:
    type_1: Translationg of type 1
    type_2: Translationg of type 1
```

Then your `select` tag can look like the following:

```
t.select(:identification_type, 
  User.identification_type_hash.map { |k,v| [t(k, scope: :identification_type), v] })
```

Of course this looks quite complicated for the view, so you could move this code to a view helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def user_identification_type_options
    User.identification_type_hash.map do |k,v| 
      [t(k, scope: :identification_type), v]
    end
  end
end
```

So your `select` tag looks like this:

```
t.select(:identification_type, user_identification_type_options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the translations in the place where you create `identification_type_hash`.

You can access the translation function anywhere in Rails via `I18n.t()`. [Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#looking-up-translations).